# Await more than one promise with Javascript / ECMAScript 6

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise

I would like to start a list of promises and execute a callback when all of then are done (without async/await).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have just figured out. Just use Promise.all:

```
function x(timeout) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(function() {
      resolve(timeout + ' done!');
    }, timeout);
  });
}

(function() {
  Promise.all([
    x(300),
    x(200),
    x(100),
  ]).then(([x300, x200, x100]) => {
    console.log(x100);
    console.log(x200);
    console.log(x300);
  });
})();
```

Comment: @AdrianHeine - you have to wait some significant amount of time (I forget the exact amount of time) before the OP can accept their own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Promise.all is your friend here.

```
Promise.all([promise1, promise2]).then(([result1, result2]) => {})
```

Any reason why you are not using async/await I find it really simplifies this pattern?

```
const [result1, result2] = await Promise.all([promise1, promise2])
```

https://www.dalejefferson.com/blog/async-await-promise-all-array-destructuring/